# Adding and Deleting Multiple Polygons in Google Maps with React - Getting Refs Right

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, polygon, react-ref

I'm using google-map-react (not react-google-maps), and is able to insert polygons by calling a function polygonDraw within my main Component (not using drawingManager). My function polygonDraw can be seen below.

I can immediately delete the newest polygon by adding polygon.setMap(null) inside my polygonDraw function.

But here is the problem: 
**I can't delete previously added polygons or all polygons. My need is to be able to delete all polygons and do this without dependency on event handlers** (like a click event on a polygon).

I tried different approaches, but had no successful implementation, including:
I'm not able to construct a Polygon component that render new google.maps.Polygon({.etc.}) objects (based on state/props).

As I'm able to insert polygons with my polygonDraw function my current thinking for strategy is: 
To **establish a reference for each added polygon.** I tried implementing React references, including Callback refs and using React.createRef. But no success. My polygonDraw is inside the main component, but outside the render. I can't figure out if it's possible to establish and store a reference to each added polygon, so reference.setMap(null) can be called for each. And if it is possible I don't know how to establish the reference (code inside constructor?, code inside polygonDraw?, code inside render including GoogleMapReact?)

Any help/advice is appreciated :-)

---

```
    polygonDraw = () => {

        let polygonCoords = [{lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng}, {.etc.}, {.etc.}]

        const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: [polygonCoords],
          fillColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0)',
        });

        polygon.setMap(this.state.map.map);
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <GoogleMapReact
                .etc.
              ></GoogleMapReact>
    )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it cuts down to performance issues, but what about saving the polygons into an array.

```
// You have to create a store (eventually in the state?)
const polygons = [];

polygonDraw = () => {

    let polygonCoords = [{lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng}, {.etc.}, {.etc.}]

    const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: [polygonCoords],
      fillColor: 'rgb(255, 215, 0)',
    });

    polygon.setMap(this.state.map.map);

    // Then use this to save it to the polygons
    polygons.push(polygon);
    // OR this if you want
    polygons.push({identifyer: "foo", polygon});

}
```

Afterwards you can just filter through the polygons array and delete the polygons you need.
I don't know if this solution will work, but you can give it a try :)

Comment: Cool Alaxander. A simple solution that worked according to my needs. Thanks a lot!

Note to readers: For reasons I won't bore anyone with I did not expect this method to work, but it did. I added a setState inside the polygonDraw function, and pushed each polygon object to an array 'polygons' in state. To delete all polygons I simply called another function and iterated over the array like this:

    this.state.polygons.forEach(polygon =>
      polygon.setMap(null)
    )